# How can I apply an external CSS class to a span created with dojo.create?

Tags: css, dojo

I'm creating a span in my web page with dojo.create, and need to apply CSS to it. I can see how to apply a style to it in the dojo reference, but I'd rather apply it via the external stylesheet (there's quite a few attributes I need to set and I'd rather not do it inline).

So given the example code below, how would I apply the CSS for the printSpan class?

```
var node = dojo.create("span", {innerHTML:_text, id:"printSpan", class:"printSpan"}, map);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write this in your external stylesheet:

```
.printSpan { color: red; }
```

This is called the [class selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#class-html).

By the way, your code should be:

```
{ innerHTML : _text, id : "printSpan", "class" : "printSpan" }
```

Notice the colon was inside the `"class"` string, though it should be outside and `printSpan` is a different string.

Comment: I just figured out I was not creating the span correctly in my real code.  Once I did that, the CSS applied automatically.  Thanks for the quick response!  Thanks for pointing out the error in the "class" too.  I'll edit the question to correct it.

Comment: @Shawn Be sure to use a string (`"class"` not `class`) because it is a [reserved word in Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words#Words_reserved_for_possible_future_use).